# Executing Pig Shell commands through PigServer API

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh

I am not able to execute shell and utility commands
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/cmds.html through PigServer
executeBatch() It fails as parsing error. Any inputs?

```
stacktrace---

rmf /tmp/cdh/output/movie-out.csv
```

> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error 
>   during parsing.   Syntax error, unexpected symbol at 
>   or near 'rmf'

Answer (score 0):

PigServer does not accept these `fs` commands directly, it seems. However, you can execute by calling methods like `deleteFile`, `mkdirs`, etc.

See http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/PigServer.html#deleteFile(java.lang.String)